# How to call a Java program from PowerShell?

Tags: java, windows, powershell

I need to call a java program (jar file )from PowerShell.
The following code works:

```
java -jar $cls --js $dcn --js_output_file $dco
```

But I need to have to run the app in a process (using `Start-Process`).

I am trying the following with no sucess:

```
Start-Process -FilePath java -jar $cls --js $dcn --js_output_file $dco -wait -windowstyle Normal
```

Error:

```
Start-Process : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'jar'.
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Knowing what the actual problem is, I would say that would be a nice thing to have in order to be able to fix it. "No success" is hardly the most verbose problem report I've ever seen :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will need to use following format for powershell:

```
 Start-Process java -ArgumentList '-jar', 'MyProgram.jar' `
-RedirectStandardOutput '.\console.out' -RedirectStandardError '.\console.err'
```

Or other option you can use is Start-job:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  & java -jar MyProgram.jar >console.out 2>console.err
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you please provide me an example using my code, I have problem in setting argumentlist

Comment: You need to add your jar name there and if any arguments.

Comment: sorry i get an error in ArgumentList, could you please provide me an example with multiple arguments to pass.....in my case are variable like $dcn and so on... thanks

Comment: You will need to quote the parameter. like "$dcn" while passing it to command.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `-jar` is being picked up as an argument of `Start-Process` rather than being passed through to `java`.

Although the documentation states that `-ArgumentList` is *optional,* I suspect that doesn't count for `-option`-type things.

You probably need to use:

```
Start-Process -FilePath java -ArgumentList ...
```

For example, in Powershell ISE, the following line brings up the Java help (albeit quickly disappearing):

```
Start-Process -FilePath java -argumentlist -help
```

but *this* line:

```
Start-Process -FilePath java -help
```

causes Powershell *itself* to complain about the `-help`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you please provide me an example using my code, I have problem in setting argumentlist

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 [Using Start-Job ScriptBlock]**

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  & java -cp .\Runner.jar com.abc.bcd.Runner.java >console.out 2>console.err
}
if ( $? == "True")
   write-host("Agent started successfully")
else if ($? == "False")
   write-host("Agent did not start")
```

**Option 2 [Using Start-Process]**

```
Start-Process -FilePath '.\jre\bin\java' -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait -ArgumentList "-cp .\Runner.jar com.abc.bcd.Runner"
```

That's how i did it using above two options initially.

**Option 3 [Using apache-commons-daemon]**

I can suggest a better and robust alternative.

You can use `apache-commons-daemon` library to build a `windows service` for your `java application` and then `start, stop` the service very conveniently.

There is amazing youtube video which will explain apache commons daemon and how to build a windows service. I will attach the reference at the end.

**References :**

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/index.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7NjdTlriM1g