# Powershell call works on server but returns error through jenkins

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins, windows-server-2019

We recently got some new Windows Server 2019 machines and I want to add them to our Jenkins setup. The problem is: 
executing any external program causes an error. docker login, git status, java -version all give an error like this

```
[TestPowershell] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\XXX~1\AppData\Local\Temp\3\jenkins1416755497082623783.ps1'"
java : java version "1.8.0_101"
At C:\Users\XXX-sa\AppData\Local\Temp\3\jenkins1416755497082623783.ps1:1 char:1
+ java -version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (java version "1.8.0_101":String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13
)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Tried it on the server itself, works fine. All the setup is the same as our 2016 servers, which dont present this issue

EDIT: I setup a vanilla master on VM 2019 and it works without this error, still presents the error with a 2016 master.

Comment: check the jenkins service, under which user is it running.. ? try the same under that user...

Comment: tried under the same user, which is an admin and it works fine on the server, only fails on jenkins. might be to do with https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/windows-security-change-affecting-powershell/ but cant find that particular security patch on my server

Comment: Use `Start-Transcript ` to log about the environment and some other details and run the script after that check the logs ..

Comment: EDIT: I setup a vanilla master on VM 2019 and it works without this error, still presents the error with a 2016 master.

Comment: I just saw your transcript file, Can you please provide part of powershell ?

Comment: `write-host "****----****"
$currentPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
$currentPrincipal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
write-host "---------"
$verbosePreference= $true
try{
Start-Transcript
java -version
}
catch{
 write-host "error:"
 $_|format-table
 write-host "----"
$_.ToString()
$_.ErrorDetails
$_.FullyQualifiedErrorId
$_.Scriptstacktrace
$_.PSMessageDetails
$_.CategoryInfo
 write-host "--"
 $_|gm
}
write-host "logged"`

Comment: I am able to replicate your issue, just open powershell ISE -> new file -> write java -version and run ( press F5 ), you will receive the same error, reason : the command produce output in 2-3 lines and powershell understand it as next command....

Comment: your problem is similar like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691344/how-to-call-a-java-program-from-powershell)

Comment: @NirajGajjar I dont think thats the same issue. jenkins runs these commands fine on my 2016 slaves with the same configuration, and it works on a 2019 master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, it seems that this is related to dotnet 4.8. Windows 2019 1809 ships with 4.7 which presents this strange error, not only does it happen on java -version, but git clone , npm install and ng build to name a few also cause the same error. Installing dotnet framework 4.8 fixes it.. in case anyone is having the same issue we were..

Answer (score 0):

Per default `jenkins-slave` service runs under the `SYSTEM` user, under which e.g. git operations will fail, since the user credentials are missing.

In the Windows `service control manager` change the user of the `jenkins-slave`-service (properties - log on) the an user profile that has appropriate permissions.

Hope that helps.

Comment: it is running under the same admin that our 2016 servers are running. still fails

Comment: EDIT: I setup a vanilla master on VM 2019 and it works without this error, still presents the error with a 2016 master.

Comment: As @NirajGajjar suggested you should turn on PowerShell transcript, or dump at least the environment via `gci env:` in your Jenkins step.

Comment: I did, it didnt give me any indication on what could be the problem.