# Windows java.exe -jar with spaces

Tags: windows, java-8, filepath, java-process-runtime

I know there are already dozens of questions out there about dealing with executing system commands that have paths with spaces in Java, but I've not found a solution to my exact situation yet.

I'm using `java.exe` that comes with jdk-1.8.x on a Windows 10 computer. The command I want to execute is as follows (I will want to use `ProcessBuilder` from within a Java program eventually, but my problem doesn't hinge on the command being executed that way; it persists if I type it directly into a terminal as well):

```sh
cmd.exe /C "G:\myself\...\My Folder\...\runtime\bin\java.exe" -jar "G:\myself\...\My Folder\...\application.jar" <app_args>
```

Both paths include `My Folder`, a directory with a space in its name. However, the path to `java.exe` works, but the path to `application.jar` does not.

I know the first path works because I can run:

```sh
cmd.exe /C "...\java.exe" -version
```

But when I attempt to run the second one the error is:

```
'G:\myself\...\My' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

**What is going on here?** Why is the path for java working, while the path for the jar is not? Does `java.exe -jar <jar_path>` parse the jar path differently than the terminal parses the java path?

Comment: Why are you using `cmd.exe /C` and not invoking `java.exe` directly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [correct quoting for cmd.exe for multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891383/correct-quoting-for-cmd-exe-for-multiple-arguments)

Comment: In terms of cmd.exe, I admit I didn't really know why it worked, but I was running this from PowerShell and java.exe would not execute unless I added that part at the beginning.

Comment: To run programs from PowerShell you need to prefix them with `./` - this is to prevent unintentionally running programs that have the same name as a built-in command (same with Bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not running `java.exe` directly - you're running `cmd.exe` and then instructing `cmd.exe` to start `java.exe`, and that's what's messing with your handling of command-line arguments.

When using `cmd.exe /C`, you need to pass it a **single** long quoted string, so you need to escape the double-quotes by doubling them up (confusingly, in this mode, single double-quote characters do not need escaping, only the leading and following quotes - it's confusing and inconsistent ("it's confusing and inconsistent" pretty much summarizes the entire Windows command-line system, but that's another story).

Try this:

```
cmd.exe /C ""G:\myself\...\My Folder\...\runtime\bin\java.exe" -jar "G:\myself\...\My Folder\...\application.jar" "<app_args>""
```

### For PowerShell

PowerShell is great once you get used to it (and I still haven't gotten used to it), but it's *annoyingly different* to the normal Windows command-line for starting other programs - simply typing the name of an executable in PowerShell will not run it, you need to use either the long-term `Start-Process` or use dot-slash `./` (the same as Bash):

From [How to call a Java program from PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691344/how-to-call-a-java-program-from-powershell)

```
Start-Process java.exe -ArgumentList '-jar', 'G:\myself\...\My Folder\...\application.jar'
```

Comment: You sure about the last double-quote pair at the end? That makes an odd number of them (7)

Comment: @owengall Good catch, the `<app_args>` **may** need to be enquoted too - it depends on what actual arguments your Java program expects.

Comment: OK, thank you very much, I checked and your explanation is correct. I did have to escape all of the inner quotes though (as in `"\`"<path>\`""` instead of `""<path>""`).